# How to vote for migration a question to Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

I would like to vote for migration a question to Super User StackExchange site but I can't.

When I try to flag the question, I choose *It doesn't belong here, or it's duplicate...*. After I choose *Off Topic because...* and now, I don't want to vote for migration to StackOverflow, thus I choose *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*.

After these choices, I don't have opportunity to vote for migration to Super User. I only have choice for Webmasters Meta, ServerFault, StackOverflow or WordPress and if I don't choose one of these possibilities, I can't flag the question correctly. Here's a screenshot of the final step:

[image]

How can I vote for migration a question to Super User?

Is it a bug (I use Google Chrome as web browser)?
Maybe I need more reputation points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't vote for migration a question to Super User.  Your only recourse is to flag the post with a custom comment along the lines of "off-topic; belongs on Super User".  Then the moderators can move it using an additional option that is only available to moderators:

[image: Moderator move option]

I wish this functionality were available to everybody with enough rep.    For example, I myself would like to vote to move questions from StackOverflow to Pro Webmasters.

Comment: Ok but I don't have the possibility to give a custom comment like you. See my screenshot.

Comment: That option is only available to moderators.

Comment: Ok, when I flag a question, I have to use _it needs ♦ moderator attention_, is that correct?

Comment: Yup, then supply a custom reason.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer.